# Where does dput write when diverting output using sink?

Tags: r

I would like to see the result of `dput` in the console while redirecting output to a file using `sink`.

```
> sink(file = 'test.txt', split = TRUE)
> x <- 2^(1:4)
> x # test.txt now contains: [1] 2 4 8 16
[1]  2  4  8 16
> dput(x) # where does this return value go?
> dput(x, file = 'test.txt') # test.txt is overwritten with: c(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Why does `x` print its value to the console (as expected), but `dput(x)` does not?

(I am using R 3.4.3 with RStudio Version 1.1.423 on Windows 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dput` is actually writing the output where expected, but it's not writing it when expected.
Running the following code shows that `dput` output remains pending until the next normal output:

```
sink(file = 'test.txt', split = TRUE)
x <- 2^(1:4)
x
dput(2*x,file="")
3*x
```

...gives a test.txt with:

```
[1]  2  4  8 16
c(4, 8, 16, 32)
[1]  6 12 24 48
```

Alternatively, running the `sink()` function to close the file will also force the pending output (but will close the connection).

```
sink(file = 'test.txt', split = TRUE)
x <- 2^(1:4)
x
dput(2*x,file="")
sink()
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why there's a difference in behavior? Also, is there any way to view the result of `dput` in the console when using `sink`?

Comment: According to the `dput` documentation, the value is "For dput, the first argument invisibly." This might be causing it to not play nicely with `sink`. I believe 'invisibly' refers to this: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/invisible.html. Couldn't find any way to split the output with dput properly.

Comment: Thanks, this has been helpful. I wonder if, because `dput` is technically writing to a file, its output is not considered "R output", as expected by `sink`.

Answer (score 1):

It only goes where you tell it to. That's what "returns invisibly" means. You can change this behavior though...

```
sink(file = "text.txt", split = TRUE)
x <- 2^(1:4)
x
# [1]  2  4  8 16
dput(x)
# returned invisibly, which is why you don't see it.
# but you can assign it to a variable

my_var <- dput(x)
my_var
# [1]  2  4  8 16

# But if you want to make it noisy, wrap it in ()
# When assigning it to a variable
(my_var <- dput(x))
# [1]  2  4  8 16

# This works even without assigning it to a variable 
(dput(x))
# [1]  2  4  8 16


# do this with your dput to sink command
(dput(x, file = "test.txt"))
# [1]  2  4  8 16
```

So, in summary, if you want to see something happen in the console that is happening behind the scenes (whether as the result of an `invisible(<return statement>)` or an assignment), wrap it in an outer layer of `()`

Comment: Wrapping it in parentheses, prints out the variable `dput` returns, but not it's actual output of dput (i.e. `c(2, 4, 8, 16)`). This will end up printing only the `[1] 2 4 8 16` to the console (undesired behavior) and both versions to the text file (desired and undesired behavior).

Comment: I see i misunderstood the question. The OP wants to know why split is not actually sending std output to both the console and the file, as advertised.  Is this correct, OP?

Comment: That is correct. Your answer has helped me understand that when one types `dput(x)` (without a sink), the value that gets printed to the console is not actually the return value. I am still wondering if it is possible to split what `dput` is writing between its connection and the connection specified by `split`.